# Trouble accessing certain spreadsheets using OAuth 2.0

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

New to Google APIs, followed the directions in 
[Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) for a basic program. Decided to make the program work using my own API Project and can access their example sheet with the new credentials, but not my own worksheet. All I'm changing is the SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, not quite sure why I'm not able to access my own spreadsheets. Even made them public. Have Sheets API enabled on the account in question.

I get this error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Here's the program: (I know its long, I'm only asking out of desperation as days of googling and torment has not been able to solve my problem)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1V7reDgXa4AuIa0hmf7cpr9SLxL0aZ0LuUXy3kBtR1uM'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A1:C'


def main():

    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[2]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see how this can be frustrating. Try this way if you'd like:

---

If you have `credentials.json` and `token.pickle` files in your application folder, along with your `quickstart.py` program, delete `credentials.json` and `token.pickle`, keep only `quickstart.py`.

Then, run `python quickstart.py` and you should get an error with **`No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'`**

Next, go to (https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started) and select a project. You mentioned that you decided to use your "own API Project", so select that one.

Next, using the left navigation menu, go to "APIs & Services" > "Library", under "G Suite" section, click on "Google Sheets API". Verify it says "API enabled". If it's not enabled for this project, then enable it.

Next, using the left navigation menu, go to "APIs & Services" > "Credentials", click on "Create credentials" > "Help me choose"

Next, at the question "Which API are you using?", select "Google Sheets API", then, at the "Where will you be calling the API from?" question, select "Other UI (e.g. Windows, CLI Tool)", then, at the question "What data will you be accessing?" choose "User data"

Once you click on "What credentials do I need?" button, it will either tell you that "You already have credentials" or it will create new credentials under "OAuth 2.0 client IDs"

Next, using the left navigation menu, go again to "APIs & Services" > "Credentials" and under "OAuth 2.0 client IDs" you should see a record with "Name", "Creation date", etc... and on the right, a button to "Download JSON". Click on it and save the file as `credentials.json` in your application folder.

Now you have two files in your application folder, `quickstart.py` and `credentials.json`.

Next, run again `python quickstart.py`.

This will will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser.

If you are not already logged into your Google account, you will be prompted to log in. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts, you will be asked to select one account to use for the authorization.

Here we're talking about the Google account to which the spreadsheet belongs. Once you select the account, you should see the "Grant ... permission" modal. Click Allow.

Next, you should see a "Confirm your choices" panel, again with an "Allow" button. Once you click on it, it goes to "The authentication flow has completed, you may close this window." and if you check your application folder, you'll see that the `token.pickle` file has been created.

Now `python quickstart.py` should have access to your spreadsheet.

---

Note: `Class Data` from `SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A1:C'` it's the name of the tab from Google's example. Your spreadsheet probably has a different name for the tab.